# mongoose multiple parameter create with middleware

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a problem with Creating with Multiple Parameter using Middleware validation,
here is my Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Order = mongoose.Schema({
 orderCode : {type: String, default : null, unique: true},
 price : {type : Number, default : 0},
 createdAt : {type : Date, default : new Date()},
 updatedAt : {type : Date, default : new Date()}
});

Order.pre("save", function(next, done){
  var self = this;
  var templateDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,"");
  mongoose.models["Order"].find({}, function(err, orders){
    if(err){
      done(err)
    } else {
      var queue = orders.length + 1;
      self.orderCode = "#"+templateDate+queue;
      done();
      next();
    }
  });
});
```

and here is my parameters and code,

```
[{"price":10000}, {"price":15000}]

models.Order.create(parameters, function(err){
...
});
```

without Using Middleware, I have created 2 data based on this parameter, but when I'm using Middleware, it just created only one but in the arguments it shows 2.

any help? thanks

Comment: you should post your middleware logic

Comment: @trquoccuong below my Schema is my Middleware logic that start with `pre`